# Can I turn Caps on/of from a batch file in Win 7?

Tags: windows-7, batch

I have a very old program that needs the commands to be all caps. when I exit this program I often forget to put the Caps Lock off (very annoying). I had a batch program in XP that did this but can't find a way to do it in Win 7.

Answer (score 8):

The only way I know from cmd.exe is by spawning powershell or vbs.

Drop this at the end of your batch, it toggles CAPSLOCK

```
start /b /wait powershell.exe -nologo -WindowStyle Hidden -sta -command "$wsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;$wsh.SendKeys('{CAPSLOCK}')"
```

That calls out to powershell via command line and invokes the sendkeys, the alternative method is to echo similar commands into a %temp% file and then `wscript %temp%\my.vbs`.

EDIT:  Here is the IF statement to ensure it only turns capslock OFF

```
start /b /wait powershell.exe -nologo -WindowStyle Hidden -sta -command "IF ([console]::CapsLock -eq 'True'){$wsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;$wsh.SendKeys('{CAPSLOCK}')}"
```

Comment: note: `[console]::CapsLock` displays current status $true or $false combined with an IF statement, you could ensure it doesn't run if capslock is already off.

Comment: Thanks knuckle-dragger. how would I incorporate the [console] line into the if statement in the batch file (I know some Basic but not much else!)? Also, how do I get the batch file to process commands after execution of the powershell line?

Comment: added example IF statement.  After the caplsock is toggled the `start /wait` will return focus to the batch script and run any further commands it finds.

Comment: This is GREAT Knuckle-dragger. I have been trying to do this for years. The only problem I have is the batch file dumps out after the first line even though I have the /wait in the start commands you have indicated. What do I need to change in the following to get it to execute the second line?

Comment: start /b /wait powershell.exe -nologo -WindowStyle Hidden -sta -command "IF ([console]::CapsLock -ne 'True'){$wsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;$wsh.SendKeys('{CAPSLOCK}')}"  <<new line>>        
net use lpt1: \\downstairs\LaserJet /persistent:yes  <<new line>>
basic mainmenu  <<new line>>
net use lpt1: /delete   <<new line>>
start /b /wait powershell.exe -nologo -WindowStyle Hidden -sta -command "IF ([console]::CapsLock -eq 'True'){$wsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;$wsh.SendKeys('{CAPSLOCK}')}"

Answer (score 1):

Using [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com/tccle-cmd-replacement.html), which can run batch scripts of course, it's as simple as the built-in [`KEYBD`](http://jpsoft.com/help/keybd.htm) command.  So your wrapper script that you run with TCC/LE would be:

```
@echo off
:: Force CAPS LOCK on beforehand.
keybd /c1
call very-old-program
:: Force CAPS LOCK off afterwards.
keybd /c0
```

Comment: Have downloaded TCC/LE and this solves the problem perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a very small program in this page http://www.rjlsoftware.com/software/utility/capslock/
it´s free and Works fine for me. Just use "capslock on" or "capslock off" in cmd.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. At the very least you should provide more than just a link, for example some additional information about the software itself.