# writing a batch file: having a batch insert a command into another cmd-based program

Tags: windows-7, command-line, java, batch

i'm trying to have my batch open another cmd based program, wait some time, then input some commands into the cmd-based program, but can't find any documentation on how to do it. this is the batch file as it is written so far:

```
:loop
start java -Xmx8192M -Xms8192M -jar minecraftforge-universal-1.6.2-9.10.1.871.jar
timeout /t 300
save-all
stop
timeout /t 120
goto loop
```

basically, the program runs then after 300 secs its supposed to save then close, then wait 120 secs, then loop. but the batch as it is right now inputs the "save-all" and "stop" commands into itself rather than the running program. i have to use the "start" command to run it in a separate instance or else the batch never runs any of the following commands.

Comment: have you used sendkeys before ?

Comment: @Knuckle-Dragger sendkeys in what? he is asking about batch. this superuser question asks about sendkeys in batch but the answers involve sendkeys in vbscript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454124/how-to-select-a-window-and-or-use-send-keys-in-batch-file    So what do you mean when you say sendkeys.  I remember in win9X there was a sendkeys 3rd party but i'ven ever seen it since. Have you run into something that works in windows 7?

Comment: I can't answer your question however you should probably use arguments [here](http://forum.feed-the-beast.com/threads/jvm-arguments-for-modded-minecraft-updated-11-11-13.28994/) for modded servers. Also, giving java more than 4GB ram is bad because it's bad at handeling it.

Comment: @barlop, W7 has powershell, so it can be done from command line in batch file.  see here http://superuser.com/questions/696467/can-i-turn-caps-on-of-from-a-batch-file-in-win-7/696477#696477

Comment: That is unless using a com-object is cheating.

Comment: @Knuckle-Dragger did some research on the sendkeys macro program. it almost does what i want except that it only seems to act into the active window. anyway to make it act into the window i need? server needs to be able to be run in the background.

Comment: Window has to be active.  Cannot be done on invisible windows, or minimized windows.  Only the foreground window. --- But maybe we could activate it, bring to front, run sendkeys, minizize it afterwords.

Comment: @Knuckle-Dragger ok, but how to activate?

Comment: We would need to know the 'title' or pid of the window to activate it.  Then call out to VisualBasic interaction AppActivate method. `[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic');
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("Notepad");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can pipe the commands into your running program. You want the left part of the pipe to wait before it echos the commands.

```
:loop
(
  timeout /t 300 /nobreak ^>nul^&echo save-all^&echo stop^&(call )
)|java -Xmx8192M -Xms8192M -jar minecraftforge-universal-1.6.2-9.10.1.871.jar
timeout /t 120 /nobreak
goto loop
```

The `(call )` is a fast method to do a no-op. The extra command is needed to prevent a trailing space from being appended to the end of the `stop` command.

If that does not work, then you definitely can do what you want using [AutoIT freeware](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

Comment: @kelik - Did the pipe work? or did you use AutoIT?